# Google Maps API - bouncing marker issue 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i'm new to javascript, hope you'll forgive me my bad if i'm doing something wrong.

In fact, i've allready found a solution for my problem, but i don't get how exactly get it into my own code.

[Google Maps API - bouncing marker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544943/google-maps-api-bouncing-marker-issue)

Unfortunately i can't just comment it because i'm new on stackoverflow.

**My Problem:**

I'm working on a map with several markers on it. If i click on a marker, i want it bouncing and switching its color by a different icon i set. All fine till this point, but at the moment all markers i clicked won't stop bouncing. I want the marker bouncing, till i click another marker. At this point the "old" marker should stop bouncing and just the new one start.

```
//Marker Icons
var unvisitedMarker = 'img/m1.svg';
var activeMarker = 'img/m2.svg';
var visitedMarker = 'img/m3.svg';



//Add Marker Function
function addMarker(props) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coords,
        map: map,
        icon: unvisitedMarker
    });

    //Opens marker information
    var marker.addListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("paperContainer").style.top = '40vh';
        document.getElementById("locationBar").style.top = 'calc(40vh - 2em)';
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        //Panby the map-position
        map.panBy(0, 350);
        //Set active Marker Icon
        marker.setIcon(activeMarker);
        //Set Marker Animation
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    });
}
```

So i got this code from the other Thread i linked from user "doublesharp":

```
// track marker that is currently bouncing
var currentMarker = null;

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById('loc-info').innerHTML = html;
        // remove the bounce from the "old" marker
        if (currentMarker) currentMarker.setAnimation(null);
        // set this marker to the currentMarker
        currentMarker = marker;
        // add a bounce to this marker
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

    });
}
```

I don't know exactly how to implement this in my owm code. And further - how do i get realized to switch the icon after it stoped bouncing to the "visitedMarker"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of that solution is to keep a reference to the clicked marker and modify that marker when a new one is clicked.

This is what I mean:

```
var currentMarker = null; // Define this variable preferably in the global context.
....
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    if(currentMarker){ // Check if there is already an active marker
       currentMarker.setAnimation(null);
       currentMarker.setIcon(visitedMarker);
    }
    currentMarker = marker;// Keep a reference to this marker because it will became active.
    document.getElementById("paperContainer").style.top = '40vh';
    document.getElementById("locationBar").style.top = 'calc(40vh - 2em)';
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    //Panby the map-position
    map.panBy(0, 350);
    //Set active Marker Icon
    marker.setIcon(activeMarker);
    //Set Marker Animation
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
});
```

Comment: It's working like a charm for the bouncing and i understand now how it works! But the icon doesn't switch to the "visited" one. The image is in the correct directory, but youre code seems to be okay too. Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Seems it's because of the positioning in the code. Even if the marker icon get's set to "visitedMarker", the line marker.setIcon(activeMarker) comes after and override the visited again. Am i right?

Comment: @Flo I've made a mistake in my example. It is fixed now. I was using `marker.setIcon(visitedMarker)` instead of `currentMarker.setIcon(visitedMarker)`.

Comment: @Flo If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it.

Comment: Top! Thank you very much, it's working how it should!

Comment: @Flo I'm glad I could help. Good luck.